# Demo hearing team voices?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

For the demos for CS-GO Comp Matchmaking or just recorded demos, i can't hear what the other team or my team is saying. Basically when i stop the recording or i go to G.O.T.V. on my matchmaking matches, i don't hear what i say when i press "k" or what my friends are teammates are saying. I really want to hear these recording because sometimes it really funny just to rehear them (and also my friend like to save these for his youtube channel but thats not really why i am focusing on this). Is there a command to enable it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demo system doesn't record voice but only the game.

To get voice recordings people use external software to record their matches (Fraps etc)